# Gardening. Potted cucumber plants

Tags: diseases

My potted cucumber plants appear to have mosaic virus.  How is an insect barrier created?

Answer (score 1):

Mosaic virus?  [Cucumber Mosaic Virus](https://www.growveg.com/plant-diseases/us-and-canada/cucumber-mosaic-virus/)

I had this this year as well:  Planted them as starts, then gave them a balanced fertilizer and have lots of ventilation, blowing fans. They started having normal colored leaves and are doing very well.  This was also a RESISTANT variety! Excelsior!  Great cucumber!

If you've got your cucumbers potted I hope that you used sterilized potting soil.  Yes?  Otherwise, you have to pay attention to rotation practices.  No Curcubits can be planted in the same soil for another 2 years.  Pots with potting soil are super for expanding one's garden real estate.

Rotation is critical for curcubits, solanaceae (tomatoes, peppers, potatoes) and brassicas (broccoli, cauliflower, kale)...Make a map of your garden every year so that you can remember what was planted where!